# Using mercurial branches for automatic deployment of website

Tags: web, mercurial, hook

I am currently thinking of a way to nicely structure my web project with mercurial. I was thinking of having two branches default (for development & testing) and release (the finished code which gets published). I would develop and test on the default branch until I have a stable application running. Then I would merge into the release branch. When I push the code to my central repository (on the server where my web application lives) I would want the code to be automatically published.

Is this the right way to go and if yes can this automatic publishing of the release branch be achieved with hooks?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the [git-flow branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? I would recommend it and also [hgflow by yujiewu](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home). The latter is an implementation of the git-flow idea for mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a "release" branch, you should name it 'stable' as several projects do.

Do you use Continuous integration yet? Maybe, you should. In Jenkins, you could create a post-build step to publish the release if everything went well. It's better than a changegroup hook.